# Getting current node paragraphs content from block

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm trying to build a block to insert on the side of the page that would list all "paragraphs" titles (from paragraph module) and link to them via an anchor (a little bit like the book module does but inside the same page)

For now i managed to get the list of paragraphs :

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$paras = $node->field_paragraphes;
```

but can't get to the list of fields and their values inside that paragraph.
When i loop over them all i seem to get is an `EntityReferenceRevisionsItem` or at best an array like :

```
array (size=2)
  'target_id' => string '8' (length=1)
  'target_revision_id' => string '12' (length=2)
```

But i can't find their fields and values ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is very similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186315/how-to-get-instance-of-referenced-entity

Comment: For the record the full path to what I was looking for was : 

`$paras = $node->field_paragraphes;
foreach ($paras as $para) {
$myValue = $para->get('entity')->getTarget()->getValue()->get('field_titre_paragraphe')->getValue();
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paragraphs are separate entities, the field just stores the reference. To access them, you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($node->field_paragraphes as $item) {
  // Access the paragraph entity like this:
  $item->entity;
}
```